# Chrome Disable "Translate This Page?" pop-up, but keep translation feature

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Chrome shows "Translate This Page?" at the translation icon. This may be helpful for first-time users who did not know that that button is there, but showing that every single time is a really stupid design. Users are not idiots; They know that they can press the translation icon if they want a translation.

I know I can disable that pop-up in the settings by disabling "Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language you read", but then the translation icon is gone from the address bar, and there seems to be no way to use the translation feature. It should be an all-or-nothing feature. For example, I am learning French, so sometimes I want to read the French pages myself (so I do not want the page to be translated), and sometimes I want translation because the page is too difficult.

How can I disable the "Translate This Page?" pop-up and keep the translation feature? Any hidden settings or extensions to use the in-built translation? I mean NOT the Google Translate extension which redirects the page to Google Translate. That is obviously different from the on-the-fly in-built translation.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Hi, have you found a way? The popup is annoying, but I want to keep the translate feature available in case I need it

Answer (score 6):

You enable / disable this setting under Advance Settings.

Turn translation on or off for all languages
You can control whether Chrome will offer to translate webpages.

On your computer, open Chrome.
At the top right, click More More and then Settings.
At the bottom, click Advanced.
Under "Languages," click Language.
Check or uncheck "Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language you read."

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Not answering the question. This will remove  translation feature on certain languages.

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi Please, note that there is a general option as well as an option (in a separate more-popup) for each listed language) I unchecked it for the listed languages only. I still have the translate icon in the address bar but the annoying popup seems to be away. (\@ThawfeekYahya: +1 - you saved my day.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff If you read the question carefully, you should know that I did disambiguate by telling two different websites with the same language. The topic is about `For a certain language it is "all or nothing"`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that to disable the popup "Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language you read" has to be disabled, and for the moment there is no option to keep the translation icon.

But, right click anywhere on the page, there still is translation option in the context menu, I find that's the best compromise

Comment: I can't solve 'auto translate but no popup'. that's what I want too